# cant get PHP_SELF to post checkbox

Tags: php, checkbox, self

i was trying to get my check box to output "Korting is ... %" at the bottom of the page depending on which check box is checked e.g. 2th and 3th boxes are checked it would output "Korting is 15%" but i cant seem to get it to work. can someone please help me 
thank you in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="nl">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>XXL Computer winkel</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>php lab 04</h3>

<table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=100%>
<form name="orderform" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<tr> 
<td> 
Korting:<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="korting" value="15" /> Student 15% <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="korting" value= "10"  /> Senior 10% <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="korting" value= "5" /> klant 5% <br/> 
<hr/>
<img src="images/Lab4/1.jpg" width="200px" height="200px" alt=" "/>
<td/>
</tr>     
<tr> 
<td>
Toshiba Satellite A100-510 basisprijs 999.99
</td>
</tr>

<tr>     
<td><!-- Shopping cart begin-->
<input type="hidden" name="toshibaproduct" value="001"/>
<input type="hidden" name="toshibamerk" value="Toshiba"/>
<input type="hidden" name="toshibamodel" value="Sattelite A100-510"/>
Aantaal: <input type="text" size=2 maxlenght=3 name="toshibaaantal" value="0"/>
<input type="hidden" name="toshibaprijs" value="999.99"/>

<input type="image" src="images/Lab4/2.jpg" border=0 value="bestellen"/>
<hr/>
</td><!--Shopping Cart END -->
</tr>
</form>
</table> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't use PHP_SELF. Without proper escaping it open a XSS hole. Just use `action=""` instead.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid in a way that will break your form in some browsers. [Use a validator](http://validator.w3.org).

Comment: @Hanky Panky ㇱ
this is all i have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <s>Use `radio` instead of `checkbox` if you want one option to be selected</s>
- Do not use PHP_SELF, it is a [security hole](http://phpsecurity.wordpress.com/2007/11/03/the-danger-of-php_self/). Instead: `<form action="">`
- <s>Access the value with `$_POST['korting']`</s>

To sum up all values, make your form like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="korting[]" value="15" /> Student 15% <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="korting[]" value= "10"  /> Senior 10% <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="korting[]" value= "5" /> klant 5% <br/>
```

and the processing like that:

```
<?php
$korting = 0;
if (isset($_POST['korting']) && is_array($_POST['korting'])) {
  $korting = array_sum($_POST['korting']);
}
echo 'Korting is ' . $korting . '%';
?>
```

Comment: I have to be able to calculate the total sum of the korting at the bottom of the page under the 2th <hr/> 
like Korting is: 15% if you checked senior box and klant box

Comment: Ah, I missed that, sorry. In that case see ThiefMasters answer and use `array_sum`. My second point still remains valid.

Comment: i don't know why but his solution is not working either or i must be doing something wrong.

Comment: seems like you did something wrong ;) Look at my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a name ending in `[]` such as `name="korting[]"`. Then you can use `$_POST['korting']` which will be an array containig the values of the checked checkboxes.

Note that `$_POST['korting']` will  not be set at all if no checkbox is checked!

Comment: its working but the 1st time the page loads it gives an error how can i get rid of that ?